# Nginx conditional logging doesn't work

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to write the body of the POST request to log file (access_400.log)  only when status 400 is received but the log file remains empty (It is created but empty). I can see in access.log the error.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

port_in_redirect off;
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status  $request_length  $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

log_format  full  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status  $request_length  $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" [$request_body]';

map $status $anyerr {
    ~^[45]  1;
    default 0;
}

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access_400.log full if=$anyerr;

sendfile        on;

keepalive_timeout  65;
"/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" 62L, 1873C                                                                                                                    52,5          52%
# Elastic Beanstalk Modification(EB_INCLUDE)

log_format healthd '$msec"$uri"'
                   '$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"'
                   '$http_x_forwarded_for';

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
# End Modification

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `access_log  /var/log/nginx/access_400.log full if=$anyerr;` should be a child of **server** and not **http**

Comment: Are you sure? The (current) nginx documentation suggests that it should work in both contexts.